# AWS Firehose FriehoseAsyncClient with PutRecordBatch (Java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am looking for an example on how to ingest data into Kinesis firehose using PutRecordBatch API and using FirehoseAsyncClient. We basically want to do this ingestion process asynchronously without waiting for the response from PutRecordBatch. However, we want to see how to handle & retry in case of failures.

Note: Currently we are using traditional way of PutRecordBatch API which for each call is taking around 1 second. We are ingesting batch of 500 records every time. We are receiving data from Kafka and ingesting into AWS Kinesis Firehose